# Matrix equality multiplication

Tags: matrices, inequality

Assume that we have the equality $x = y$ for $x,y \in R^n$. can one conclude that $Ax = Ay$, for a given matrix A.

If it helps, one can assume that $A$ is positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=y$, then we have $Ax=Ay$.

Since we are multiplying $A$ with the same vector, we do not need to assume $A$ is positive semi-definite as long as $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

In general, if $x=y$ and $f$ is a function, then we have $f(x)=f(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it for a second. If $x=y$ that means that $x$ and $y$ are simply *two symbols for the same thing*. That means you can replace any instance of $x$ with $y$ and vice versa. Hence, obviously you have that
$$Ax = Ay $$
Because $Ax$ is simply another way to write $Ay$ because $x$ and $y$ are the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from $x=y$ we get $Ax=Ay$, by the definition of the matrix-vector product.

Comment: It's not really by definition of the matrix product; it's a general property of equality. If two things are equal and an operation is done to both, then you get the same result because they were the same to begin with.